# SignalR Javascript Client callbacks is not being triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, signalr

I am able to connect to my Hub and I've hooked up OnConnected and OnDisconnected. They should add/subtract from a integer and call a client callback with the new value.
My angular application is connecting to the server successfully but my registered callback function is not being triggered.

Here is my Serverhub:

```
[HubName("online")]
public class OnlineHub : Hub
{
    private static int userCount = 0;

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        userCount++;
        Clients.All.listUpdated(userCount);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {

        userCount--;

        Clients.All.listUpdated(userCount);

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

And here's my Angular SignalRService:

```
import { AppSettings } from './../app.settings';
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;

@Injectable()
export class SignalRService {

  // Declare the variables
  private onlineHub: any;
  // create the Event Emitter
  public messageReceived: EventEmitter<any>;
  public connectionEstablished: EventEmitter<Boolean>;
  public connectionExists: Boolean;

  constructor(private appSettings: AppSettings) {
    // Setup
    this.connectionEstablished = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
    this.messageReceived = new EventEmitter<any>();
    this.connectionExists = false;
  }

  // This method gets executed from angular controller
  public initialize(proxyName: string): void {
    this.onlineHub = $.connection.online;

    this.onlineHub.client.listUpdated = function(list: any): void {
      console.log(list);
      this.messageReceived.emit(list);
    };

    this.startConnection();
  }

  private startConnection(): void {
    $.connection.hub.url = this.appSettings.SIGNALR_BASE_URL + '/signalr';
    $.connection.hub.start()
      .done((data: any) => {
        console.log('SignalR Connected with: ' + data.transport.name);
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
        this.connectionExists = true;
      })
      .fail((error: any) => {
        console.log('SignalR could not connect: ' + error);
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);
      });
  }

  private registerOnServerEvents() {
    this.onlineHub.client.listUpdated = function(list: any): void {
      console.log(list);
      this.messageReceived.emit(list);
    };
  }
}
```

I am registering my callback "listUpdated" before I run start() as the documentation says and $.connection.hub contains client.listUpdated before start() is called so it should register. But still, the OnConnected method is not called.

Comment: Which method is not being hit?  The server side OnConnected(), the client side listUpdated() handler, or both?

Comment: @Learning2Code Both, but the error is probably on the serverside OnConnected() since that method in turn is calling listUpdated() on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by surrounding the OnConnected() and OnDisconnected() code in try/catch block and created a clientside method called "error" that returns eventual exceptions to the client. That way I found out that I had a Json Serialization issue.

My Hub now looks like this:

```
    [HubName("online")]
    public class OnlineHub : Hub
    {
        private static int userCount = 0;


        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                userCount++;
                Clients.All.listUpdated(userCount);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Clients.All.error(exc);
            }

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            try
            {
                userCount--;
                Clients.All.listUpdated(userCount);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Clients.All.error(exc);
            }

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }
```

And I register the error callback on the js client BEFORE calling start():

```
this.onlineHub.client.error = (exc: any): void => {
  console.log('Error occured:', exc);
};
```